# How to select path of directory and fire command via terminal using JAVA code

Tags: java, command, processbuilder

How to select the path of a directory and then fire a set of commands using JAVA coding.
For example, I want to stop and start the tomcat server (terminal) like,

```
 1. cd home/softwares/tomcat/bin

 2. sh shutdown.sh

 3. sh startup.sh
```

I am getting path(1) from user as input.If I use process builder, it shows error as cd is not a proper command. Please any one provide me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("shutdown.sh");
 pb.directory(new File("/home/software/tomcat/bin"));
 Process p = pb.start();
}
```

Comment: Just a block of code is not a high quality answer.  A better answer explains what the code does and why the approach was chosen.

Comment: The block of code is the code needed to do what user3560068 desires to do.  I would add that pb.directory is essentially the replacement for cd but that seems fairly obvious.